# Display accented characters

Tags: php, sqlite, character-encoding

In command line, sqlite correctly displays the accented characters contained in my database.
In PHP, echo shows me correctly as well.

But when I do a query from my PHP page, it does not display correctly. I can not find where the encoding problem is.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('database.sqlite');

if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $rec = htmlentities($_GET['search']);
} else { 
    $rec = ''; 
}

$result3 = $db->query('SELECT lastname,firstname,phone,location FROM rh WHERE name != "" AND lastname || " " || firstname  || " " || location LIKE "%'.$rec.'%" ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 25');
?>
```

The HTML form :

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="search" name="search" value="<?php echo $rec; ?>" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

And the results on another php page :

```
<?php
echo '<h3>Results</h3>';
echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Location</th></tr>';
while ($row = $result3->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['lastname'] . ' ' . $row['firstname'] . '</td><td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td><td>' . $row['location'] . '</td></tr>';
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to specify the propper encoding in your HTML-Head e.g.:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...
  </head>
```

And/or you need to de/encode your data before output `utf8_encode();`.

Comment: I just tried, unfortunately it does not change anything. `echo '<tr><td>' . $row['lastname'] . ' ' . utf8_encode($row['firstname']) . '</td><td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td><td>' . $row['location'] . '</td></tr>';`